# Asymptotic Notation cormen_doubt

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

why $2^{2n}$ is asymptotically greater than $n!$?
My Attempt is that $n!=o(n^n)$..that means it can grow as high as $n^n$ then how it is asymptotically smaller than $2^{2n}$....don't suggest use of calculator!

Comment: What is cormen_doubt?

Comment: I suspect the assertion is that $2^{2^n}$ is asymptotically greater than $n!$. Can you re-check?

Comment: refer problem 1 https://carlstrom.com/stanford/cs161/ps1sol.pdf @DanielFischer

Comment: @sourav, in the document you link it says that $2^{2^n} > n!$, **NOT** that $2^{2n} > n!$.

Comment: Really ..??is it 2^2^n??? and is 2^2^n >n! ?@AntonioVargas

Comment: What do you mean "really"? See for yourself. And yes, $2^{2^n} > n!$ for large $n$ since $\log n! \sim n \log n$ while $\log 2^{2^n} = 2^n \log 2$.

Answer (score 2):

$2^{2n}$ is not asymptotically greater than $n!$.

If we can use the fact that the series
$$
e^4=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^n}{n!}
$$
converges, then we see that $4^n/n!$ goes to $0$. Hence, $n!$ grows faster than $2^{2n}$.

Comment: my question is from problem 3.3 page 61(Introduction to algorithm -CLRS -3rd edition) and  when i googled the answer many shown that 2^(2n)>n!,so i had the doubt...but is my approach correct that n!=o(n^n) so we can easily conclude that 2^2n will never br greater than n^n!! ?@Cm7F7Bb

Comment: @sourav $n!=o(n^n)$ says that $n!$ grows slower than $n^n$ (which is true), but it does not help you to determine the limit $2^{2n}/n!$.

Comment: but here see the solution  https://carlstrom.com/stanford/cs161/ps1sol.pdf   @Cm7F7Bb

Comment: i checked many link in the google got 2^(2n)>n! as answer  http://clrs.skanev.com/03/problems/03.html

Comment: it is not the correct way of checking this ...!!!you must try for a bigger number ...for which you can't !

Comment: i mean 2^(2n) is asymptotically greater than n!

Comment: You can say 2^(2n) have higher order of growth than n!

Comment: @sourav But I showed in my answer that exactly the opposite is true. Actually, for large values of $n$, $2^{2n}<n!$.